# C# Delegate confusion and lack of knowledge

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I'm so confused with delegates, my mind is going to eat itself.

I want to connect two different threads to do stuff to one-another.
But obviously, "cross-thread calls are unsafe" exceptions all over the place, demanding I provide delegates instead. I have read countless tutorials, documentations, examples, and I only die a little more inside with each example, because I try it, it just *does not work*.

Here's my set-up in simplified, code-free way:

I have two threads

.

**THREAD1** which has **Class DISPLAY_WITH_RICHTEXTBOX**

That class has a **RICH_TEXT_BOX** which I will be editing.

That class has a method **int WRITE_TO_TEXTBOX_AND_RETURN_FEEDBACK(string Text)**

.

**THREAD2** which has **Class SOME_CONTROL_PANEL**

That class has a **TEXT_BOX_OF_DOOM** with some text in it

That class has a **BUTTON_OF_MAGIC** which will call the method from the other class to add the textbox's text to the richtextbox. Upon execution of the method, the method will return back to me an *int* with the new total size of the Rich text box's text.

.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to make this structure the neatest.

1. Do I explicitly manipulate the controls VIA a delegate or something, making THREAD2 an upgrade to THREAD1, making it easy to take in/out of the code
2. Do I call a method to do the editing for me, which would make the THREAD1 class *dependent* on the THREAD2 class?

And how do I actually build the delegate. Every time I try anything, anywhere, the code complains delegates can only be used with things that are **static**, but that is HIGHLY impractical for what I'm aiming to create. I can workaround this by making some variables in THREAD1, edit them from THREAD2, and let THREAD1 figure out what to do with the variables, therefore passing all the interactions from THREAD2>THREAD1. But that makes my THREAD1 code so untidy and un-neat I wanna cry.

Is there another way of calling functions from THREAD2 -> THREAD1 that's neat and doesn't involve variables and custom thread-locking-code-of-doom to manage the variables and stuff?

I hope I can be understood what I mean.

.

I just want to have a
THREAD1 > CLASS1 > Rich Text Box

That I can edit with the use of THREAD2 > CLASS2 > Button
So that I don't edit -anything- in THREAD1 > CLASS1

I'm aiming to make that THREAD2 stuff a complete *addon* to the program, making the dependency only one-way (Thread2 depends on Thread1, without Thread1 expecting it)

If it's impossible to make Thread1 oblivious to Thread2, can I at-least make the Thread1 involvement minimal?

.

Edit: If Delegates and other related stuff is not what am I looking for, WHAT AM I looking for, if I want to get seperate pieces of code to run in their own threads, independent of eachother, but mess with eachother to achieve a greater goal; such as they editing eachother in any way;, so
1. I develop "class MY PROGRAM" to run on its own, later I make an addon
2. "class MY ADDON" which messes with MY PROGRAM however it wants, without needing to go back and edit the MY PROGRAM code to allow communication between the two programs.
Is there a programming language that can achieve this, if C# cannot?

Comment: It is *very* unusual for a program to have UI on multiple threads. Why do you need that? Move everything to one UI thread.

Comment: It's impossible for me to do that. The second UI thread is doing it's own things, in my case, being a server. It needs to reply as fast as possible, and log things back to the UI which needs to also respond quickly. I don't want the server class to lose performance just to draw a stupid UI. It's just trying to pass data to the UI, without the UI being "too involved" to avoid performance loss (such as a simple method call from the other thread; no additional crap), but data locking is making it impossibe; ow do I disable data locking?

Comment: Surprising. How can your 2nd UI thread be a "server" at the same time? You shouldn't block the UI thread because that will make the UI hang. Can't you have a single UI thread and other threads doing the bulk of the work (like running the "server")? UI controls can only be accessed on the UI thread because enythign else would be racy.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I  use on form app to hop between threads and change UI controls

```
Program.MainForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

    //do changes here  

});'
```